# Route output to bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, avaudiosession

For an `AvAudioSession` I am able to switch between speaker and earpiece using the

```
// To speaker
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
BOOL enableSpeaker = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AvAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];

// To earpiece
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
BOOL enableSpeaker = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AvAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
```

Is there a way to route to bluetooth if it is connected. The `AudioSessionSetProperty` is deprecated so do not want to use that.I need a way to switch between speaker, earpiece and bluetooth.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? When BT is connected, that is supposedly the the default route for playback.

Comment: This is not related to Bluetooth Low-Energy (CoreBluetooth.framework), right? As far as I know, BLE isn't good enough for Audio.

Comment: You are right it routes to bluetooth.But how do I change between bluetooth and earpiece.If bluetooth is there in that case when I do AvAudioSessionPortOverrideNone it goes to bluetooth.How can I route to earpiece.

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?